# whenever I check the git status under untracked files I am getting this ./ nothing else I want this to be ignored by the git

Tags: git, gitignore

```
git status
On branch master

No commits yet

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    ./

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add the directory in `.gitignore` and that should get rid of that.

Comment: It seems the current folder you are in now is untracked?

Comment: Regardless of this problem or not, adding an empty `.gitignore` as the first commit on any repository is a great idea since that commit is a universal common base for absolutely everything, and will make things like for instance merging unrelated repositories later trivial. So do always create a commit with an empty `.gitignore` as the first commit. Then on subsequent commits you can ignore whatever you want.